# After join 3 tables MySQL returned an empty result

Tags: mysql, sql

Four tables I joined all together.it worked successfully. today onwards it is not working. after executing the query no error but MySQL returned an empty result set i don't why.i wrote the table and the queries below

**Category**

```
Id cat_name status
1   tv         1
2   mobile     1
```

**Brand**

```
Id brand_name status
1   samsung     1
2    nokia      1
```

**Discount**

```
id  barcode_id  discount_name  discount_type    amount
 1    222            fix         percentage       5
```

**Product table**

```
Id p_name    p_description cat_id brand_id warranty cost_price retail_price 
1  samsung4  samsung4 only  2         1       2        30000     40000

reorderlevel barcode   add_date     status
20              222   2018-07-20      1
```

**sql query**

```
 select p.id,p.p_name,p.p_description,c.catname,b.brand_name,p.warranty,p.cost_price,p.retail_price,d.discount_type,d.amount,p.reorderlevel,p.barcode,p.add_date,p.status from product p, brand b, category c,discount d where p.brand_id = b.id and p.cat_id = c.id and p.barcode = d.barcode_id and p.barcode = '222'
```

after executing the query no error but MySQL returned an empty result set

Comment: I guess there are no rows in the `discount` table with `barcode_id = "222"`?

Comment: There are 4 tables in your query but only 3 defined in the question can you add discount . You should also move from implicit to explicit joins.

Comment: yes sir 4 tables i didn't above with discount table

Comment: Do `barcode` and `bardcode_id` have the same type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are no rows in discount table with `222` barcode
or else please try using joins rather than comma seperated query

Please check if barcode and barcode_id have same datatype

```
 select p.id,p.p_name,p.p_description,c.catname,b.brand_name,p.warranty,p.cost_price,p.retail_price,d.discount_type,d.amount,p.reorderlevel,p.barcode,p.add_date,p.status 
from product p
join brand b on p.brand_id = b.id
join category c on p.cat_id = c.id
join discount d on p.barcode = d.barcode_id
where p.barcode = '222'
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically your query appears to be fine. Based on the data you have provided, visually it looks like the data is also fine but we can't see a few details (such as trailing/leading whitespace or mismatching types).

Using "SHOW COLUMNS FROM [table]", ensure that your column types match where you are trying to do comparisons. MySQL does cast types but your types should align.

Secondly, ensure you have no leading/trailing whitespace in any of your IDs being used in the join - It's difficult for us to see from the information provided whether that is definitely the case but it would explain your issues if any of your columns being used in the join are char types.